# What does "to make pale" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, literature

> And then the Milliner — and the Man
> Of the Appalling Trade —
> To take the measure of the House —
> There'll be that Dark Parade —

**Meaning**:
What you might not know—but Dickinson probably did—is that *"appalling" comes from the Latin word for "**to make pale**,"* as the undertaker was responsible for preparing the body right there in the home.

Could anyone please show me what is the concept or meaning of the italic part?

([Source](http://www.shmoop.com/theres-been-a-death-in-the-opposite-house/stanzas-5-6-summary.html))

Comment: I assume I've guessed correctly what you intended to be the "italic part". Please edit accordingly if not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's important to recognize that *Latin is not English*. The Latin root (such as "to make pale") of an English word ("appalling") will rarely make sense on their own. "To make pale" is ungrammatical as a direct translation to English.

That being said, it's likely that it means that "to make pale" is to make a person go pale, usually at disgust or horror. This fits the scene if I'm correct in saying that it's from when a death occurs.

> [The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/pale): To cause to turn pale.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't take too much notice of the possibility that the author knew the Latin origin of *appalling*, with reference to *making pale (light-coloured)*.

It doesn't seem particularly relevant to the poetic context here, where most readers would probably be put in mind of [***pallbearers***](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/pallbearer) (from a completely different Latin root, *pallium*, a covering, shroud, cloak).

It's pretty clear *that appalling trade* is the trade of the [*undertaker/funeral director*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/undertaker?s=t). The text goes on to mention *that Dark Parade* (the funeral procession), where Dickinson uses figurative *dark = sombre, foreboding*, so it seems unlikely she actually *wanted* the corresponding associations of *pale = light = non-serious, frivolous, mood-lifting*. I think OP's cited study notes are simply "over-analysis".